# In Django and DRF, why would an api route request.user return an AnonymousUser instance, while django.contrib.auth.get_user(request) return the user?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Let's take a very simple route:

```py
class Highscore(APIView):
    def get(request):
        user = request.user
        highscore = user.highscore
        return Response({"highschore":highscore})
```

For some unknown reason, there are cases in which `request.user` **despite having the user authenticated and logged in (!)** return an `Anonymous User` instance rather than the user itself.

However, this can be bypassed by using `get_user` util function from `django.contrib.auth`.

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user

class Highscore(APIView):
    def get(request):
        user = get_user(request)
        highscore = user.highscore
        return Response({"highschore":highscore})
```

What could be the cause of that?

Important note: The user is for sure logged in. So much so that when opening the admin website in a different tab, it recognizes the correct user just from the session. If it is and admin it presents the admin content and if not if give the "you are logged in as ... but this view is reserved for admin users".

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missed to add the **`authentication_classes`** class attribute in the view class,

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication


class Highscore(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication]

    def get(self, request):
        user = request.user
        highscore = user.highscore
        return Response({"highschore": highscore})
```